# Where is the documentation for the layout of the template .tex file for r/exams

Tags: r, r-exams

I'm trying to generate a set of exams using R/exams (software of which I'm very impressed by the way). For our University College, we need to apply a certain template for our exams. We have a `.sty` file for it, but I'm unable to include it in the LaTex template. I have tried all the options per documentation

Using the inputs variable:

```
exams2pdf(myexam, n = 1, name = c("pdf-examen", "pdf-oplossing"),
          encoding = "UTF-8",
          showpoints = "TRUE",
          dir = "output",
          edir = "oefeningen",
          inputs = "/Users/eothein/education/examentest/templates/hogent-examen.sty",
          template = c("templates/opgave.tex", "templates/oplossing.tex"),
         )
```

I have tried relative paths, absolute paths but the LaTeX compiler complains it cannot find the `.sty` file.

On top of that, it is very difficult to find documentation on how to use the metainfo/regular info from R into the LateX file. I'm starting from the template file generated from `exams_skeleton` but it is unclear how to work with it (without a lot of trial and error). Is there documentation for this? E.g. I guess `%% \exinput{questionnaire}` generates the questions, but how can I tweak this?

Kind regards

Jens Buysse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general I would recommend to include such `.sty` files in your personal `texmf` tree, e.g., in `texmf/tex/latex/hogent-examen.sty` or `texmf/tex/latex/hogent/hogent-examen.sty`. This way they are found from every location on your machine.

Your solution via the `inputs=` argument should have worked as well, tough. It's hard to tell what exactly went wrong without a fully reproducible example.

As for your general question about the documentation for the `exams2pdf()` templates, see `vignette("exams", package = "exams")`, specifically Section 3.

*Historical note:* This is actually quite an old document (including various updates, though), originally written more than a decade ago and long before R/exams had the capabilities it has today. I should turn the most important details from that paper into a blog post for R-exams.org (which is less than 3 years old). However, I didn't get round to doing this, though.

Comment: The remark on the .sty files is justly, but I want the .sty file to be in the same folder as the template: this way somebody else can clone my repo and generate exams without the need to install the .sty file in its latex dir.

Comment: vignette("exams", package = "exams") gives some general info, but not everything: e.g. how can I get all the points etc. Is there an API available or something?

Comment: Regarding the sty file: Please provide a reproducible example. Regarding the points: I'm not sure what you mean by "get all the points". Possibly this is a separate question? An "API" does not exist because the process isn't really an interface - it's just a couple of placeholders that are replaced in the template.

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. With the points I mean, I want to show how much points a student can get answering a question, and also generate a total of all the points in de preamble of the exam. I know there is something like `numpoints` for the metadata, but this doesn't do anything

Comment: That should best be discussed in a separate question and not here. See this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61210271/how-to-display-points-per-exercise-when-printing-to-pdf-via-exams2pdf There a workardound is described - but I'm currently also working on a more flexible solution as well.